# WYSIWYG software for bulding Android activities?

Tags: android, xml, layout, wysiwyg

I've started programming for Android this week, and I'm ok with all the programming thing, but the layout stuff frustrates me.
**Are there any WYSIWYG software that act like when you use an AbsoluteLayout* in the ADT?** Like, a software that lets you drop views and automatically writes the XML.
*AbsoluteLayout is deprecated D:!! So I guess I shouldn't use it (BTW, what happens if I do?).

Comment: "BTW, what happens if I do?" -- your UIs will not readily adapt to different screen sizes. There are Android device screens at just about every size between 2.7" and 6" in tenth of an inch increments, plus a variety of tablet sizes in the 6"-and-up range. If you want to intelligently use that space, you need to learn how to design Android UIs using other container classes besides `AbsoluteLayout`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have already done a couple of apps using LinearLayout & RelativeLayout, but they are reeally a pain in the ass. I can't believe it's that difficult to implement some kind of WYSIWYG software :/

Answer (score 2):

Try [IntelliJ IDEA 12](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/android.html) for an alternative to Eclipse. It includes a powerful UI designer (as evidenced in [this video](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/06/android-ui-designer-coming-in-intellij-idea-12/)).

Also take a look at [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) (still under development) which is built on IntelliJ and provides additional UI tools to assist you in designing adaptive UIs for different screen sizes.

[Deprecation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) denotes that a feature has been superseded by another feature, and it could be removed in future versions of the SDK. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) recommends using a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`.